# Flagging a question as containing sensitive information

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Within a number of questions I have come across recently (I know it happens a lot) sensitive data has been accidentally leaked. Whether accidental or intentional it happens and resolution should be fast and as easy as possible.

According to the following post [(What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or) and [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/174508) the correct process of reporting leaked sensitive information should be:

1. edit out the information.
2. flag the post with "other" to get moderator intervention.

As security and leaked information could potentially be an immediate threat I was wondering about the following to hopefully stream line and catch more instance of this sooner.

1. **Could a flag be present specifically for flagging security related issues within a question?**

At the moment a two step process (edit and raise) seems lacking and requires the community to know to do this. I also feel the current method does not raise the issue to the original author with information on why its bad and what they should do to fix it in an immediate and obvious way.

2. **The current process is a two step process means people may not appropriately raise the issue to the moderation team and therefore keys could remain in history** (i know its the internet and things never truely go away but still).

I would like to know what others think of the current "guidance", does it do enough, and could/ should improvements be made around this?

Comment: What improvements would you suggest?

Comment: Once the beans are spilt there's nothing we can do.

Comment: You can post a comment to the author telling them to change their secrets immediately, but we can't undo what they did. We can try to minimize the damage by censoring this information, but this is not time critical anymore as the details have been shared with the world already.

Comment: I would like to see a flag option on questions so to mark as containing sensitive data it could raise it to moderators, but also add a comment to the question explaining what the user should do as next steps. Many new devs might not know to rotate apikeys, change passwords etc.

I know once a cat has been let out the bad its out. But we could at least help raise this to the author point them in the right direction because cats hit the fan.

Comment: *"but also add a comment to the question explaining what the user should do as next steps"* - we specifically _don't_ do that because then it encourages people to look for those details in the post/revision history.

Comment: Ahhh good point, didnt think of that :|

Comment: _"Well, everything raised to mods has some kind of urgency. Also the only one who can actually react is the OP by changing the secret."_ right but how many new devs realize the severity of what they have done (potentially).

Comment: What would be the safe way to raise the issue to someone unsuspecting of what they have done?

Comment: You _could_ keep an eye on the post until you see that the redaction has been made, and only once the content has been redacted from both the post and the post history, then comment about what happened and what they can do to defend themselves.

Comment: Sure, but this is quite a bit of effort in many ways. Do mods write the reason something was redactited. Otherwise question authors are completely blind to the situation they have put themselves in. Being made aware means they can be proactive. Being blind means your a sitting duck.

Comment: That is true, but there are multiple grades of secret. Those which someone can do something about and those which are too late once out in the public domain. But the idea behind this was to talk about improving the flagging process so it can be made clearer to the author as to what they have done.

Comment: Bear in mind that there are various sites that copy SO data and numerous other processes that scrape SO, so even if the sensitive data is nuked within minutes it may have already been picked up.

Answer (score 11):

The only thing that any sensible site could do is remind its users of good operational security and reasonable security practices.

- Don't post anything sensitive.
- Only post what you have permission to post.
- If you post something sensitive, *assume it is compromised* and rotate credentials as necessary.

Here's a timely reminder - this removal of sensitive data is a courtesy, not a guarantee.  Flagging it doesn't really change the fact that someone accidentally posted their production DB's credentials on the Internet.  (And yes, it's happened before.)

Comment: "this removal of sensitive data is a courtesy, and happens more on staff's availability, not moderator availability." - ummm no? Redactions require two moderators, and doesn't need any staff members to give a stamp of approval at any step in the process. Staff intervention is only needed if an image hosted on Stack's imgur needs to be nuked

Comment: @Zoe:  there must've been some changes recently.  Thanks for the info - I'll update this then.

Comment: [Feb 2016?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision/274274#274274) I guess if you consider that recent is a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 8):

**We shouldn't add a dedicated flagging option, because flagging this stuff is *mostly* pointless**.  We don't really want to encourage people to send more flags about this.

Once your credentials are leaked, **there is only one correct solution: change the credentials**.

Anything else isn't enough to stop anyone monitoring the internet for leaked credentials (which people absolutely do), because they've already seen them.

A more prominent flagging option would generate more such flags, creating additional work for moderators and potentially luring posters into a false sense of security that their credentials are safe, when in fact they need to change them ASAP.

Comment: You right. Changing the credentials is something people should do. My point being that the author of the question should be made aware of what they have done in an obvious (but maybe private way). At the moment the comments system and redaction may not bring the severity to the users attention.

Answer (score 3):

*The two-step process is sensible.*
The purpose of the edit and flag are separate:

1. The edit is used to remove the information *immediately* from the directly visible locations.
2. The flag is used  to remove the information *permanently* from secondary locations.

No matter how fast a mod can react to the flag, the reporter is the only one who can act immediately. Even if there were a specialised flag that mods would react to faster, the reporter acting immediately via an edit would still be appropriate to lessen the damage.

Furthermore, a specialised flag would not remove the option to edit. Someone who is not aware that editing is not sufficient would likely still just edit and not flag even with a specialised flag.

Comment: The only concern I would have is when personal data leaks, scrubbing the data without the offender being involved would potentially cause them to be unable to inform the victims.

Comment: @Gimby Same here, but I don't think a special flag would solve that either.

Comment: Well maybe it would if part of the handling of that flag would be to actually safeguard a copy of the original state for X time, which can be delivered to the offender upon request.